# Growth of $a^{b^n}$ vs. $n^n$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, discrete-mathematics, asymptotics

I've been going through some lecture notes on discrete mathematics, and there is a theorem describing the asymptotic "pecking order" of certain functions:
$$1\prec\ln\ln n\prec\ln n\prec n^\epsilon\prec n\prec n^a\prec n^{\ln n}\prec a^n\prec n^n\prec a^{b^n}\text{ where }0<\epsilon<1<a,b.$$
Unfortunately, this theorem is stated without a proof. For the past hour, I've been trying to figure out a proof for the last relation $$n^n\in o(a^{b^n})$$ but I'm stuck... my attempts so far included trying to make sense of $$\frac{c_{n+1}}{c_n}\text{ where }c_n=\frac{a^{b^n}}{n^n},$$
applying L'Hôpital's rule on ${a^{b^n}}/{n^n}$ which gave me
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a^{b^n}}{n^n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{a^{b^n}}{n^n}\cdot\frac{\ln a\ln b\ b^n}{1+\ln n}\right),$$
and trying to prove inductively that $a^{b^n}>n^n$ from some point, but currently it seems like I'm running out of ideas.
I'd appreciate any hint (or solution), I don't *need* the proof for my studies, but I'd love to understand it nonetheless.

Comment: $n^n\lt(2^n)^n=2^{n^2}\lt2^{2^n}$

Answer (score 7):

Approach: The inequality is hard to understand because of the double exponential. So get rid of it by taking a logarithm.

---

The inequality

$$n^n \le a^{b^n}$$

is true if and only if

$$\ln n^n \le \ln a^{b^n}$$

which is true if and only if

$$n \ln n \le b^n \ln a.$$

Now if $a, b > 1$, this is true for large $n$ - the right side grows exponentially, while the left grows slower than $n^2$, for example.

Comment: You really don't want inequalities all along. They only hold asymptotically -- for some settings of $a,b$ and small $n$, they won't hold.

Comment: Yes, sorry; I only meant that this holds for large $n$ (and wanted to leave the asker something to do!).

Comment: Anyway, +1 if only for the first sentence. *If powers or exponentials look confusing, take the logarithm.*

Comment: Thanks - I think I've got it now: $a^{b^n}\in\omega(n^n)$ iff $\lim(n^n/a^{b^n})=0$ iff $\lim(n\ln n-b^n\ln a)=-\infty$ iff (since $n\ln n,b^n\ln a>0$) $n\ln n\in o(b^n\ln a)$ iff $\lim(n\ln n/b^n\ln a)=0$ which is true by l'Hôpital's rule since it equals $\lim(1/(\ln a\ln^2 b\ n b^n))$.

Answer (score 3):

Let $a, b > 1$.  Note that $n \log_a n \leq o(n^2) \leq o(b^n)$.  Then

\begin{align}
n^n &= a^{n \log_a n} \\
{} & \leq a^{o(n^2)} \\
{} & \leq a^{o(b^n)} \\
{} & \leq o(a^{b^n})
\end{align}